# Retrieving value from a module.exports array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I'm trying to retrieve the values from this module.export array and I just can't. Can you help me?

This is words.js

```
 module.exports = {
    "word1": 'phrase1',
    "word2": 'phrase2',
    "word3": 'phrase3',
    "word4": 'phrase4',
    "word5": 'phrase5'
 };
```

And on main.js I'm calling

```
var recipes = require('./words');
```

Now, how can I retrieve the values of words.js to use in main.js

I mean, if I want to get a random number [3] then show the respective value [phrase4]?

This what I was trying to do but it didn't work at all.

```
var factIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * recipes.length);
var randomFact = recipes[factIndex];
```

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve a random property value from an objects by using object array of keys [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or object array of entries [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

**Object.keys()**:

```js
const recipes = {"word1": 'phrase1',"word2": 'phrase2',"word3": 'phrase3',"word4": 'phrase4',"word5": 'phrase5'},
  recipesKeys = Object.keys(recipes),
  factIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * recipesKeys.length),
  randomFact = recipes[recipesKeys[factIndex]];

console.log(randomFact);
```

**Object.entries():**

```js
const recipes = {"word1": 'phrase1', "word2": 'phrase2', "word3": 'phrase3', "word4": 'phrase4', "word5": 'phrase5'},
  recipesEntries = Object.entries(recipes),
  factIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * recipesEntries.length),
  randomFact = recipesEntries[factIndex][1];

console.log(randomFact);
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue, and I was able to get it to work using this solution. However, I don't understand how it converted the `[{"word1":"phrase1","word2":"phrase2", "word3":"phrase3"}]` to an array. I would appreciate if you could explain.

Comment: @UmarAftab you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 3):

You should consider exporting an array.
Like this for example:

```
module.exports = {
  words: ['phrase1','phrase2','phrase3',...]
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
var words = require('./path/to/file').words;

//You can now loop it and you have a .length property
words.map(function(word){ console.log(word) })
console.log(words.length)

//getting a specific value is also done by the index:
var myFirstPhrase = words[0];
```

OR if your file is only exporting that word list, you can even get rid of the surrounding object and export the Array directly:

```
module.exports = ['phrase1','phrase2', ...];
```

And import it like this:

```
var words = require('./path/to/file');
```

Comment: Thank you @JoschuaSchneider but someone just posted the exact answer. This one looks great also but I really need to use array of objects.

Comment: No problem, but you could have just altered my code to export an array of objects. That saves you the Object.keys() loop and so on

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, module.exports is meant for functions. A module is a container for functions you can call in another file.

What you want, is to store a list of strings and iterate over its content. I suggest using either an array which will let you loop through or access values using random numbers [3] or create a json file.

Comment: Hey @Alexander Luna someone just posted the exact answer. Check it out to see what I was looking for. Thanks for the attention!